# How do I check if an active storage video has been watched completely in rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I want to define a rails function (def completed?) that checks if a lesson has been watched completely. (@lesson.completed? should return true if a user has watched it completely and false if they have not)

I have currently defined a JS function that alerts the user once a lesson has ended. But I don't know how to define a rails function that returns if a user has watched a video.

Lesson Model:

```
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  has_one_attached :file
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :course_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Lesson Migration:

```
class CreateLessons < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :lessons do |t|
      t.text :name
      t.references :course, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :lessons, [:course_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

Lessons/Show.html.erb:

```
<h2><%= @lesson.name %></h2>
<video id="video" controls="true" width="auto" height="auto">
 <source src="<%= url_for(@lesson.file) %>" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
<script>document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("ended", function(){alert("all done")}, true);
</script>
```

Comment: How do you determine whether a user watched the lesson?

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's my question. Right now I just use a javascript function: document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("ended", function(){alert("all done")}, to check if a user has watched a lesson. But I want to define a rails method that does the same.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Also the JS function only alerts the user if a video has been watched. It doesn't return true if a user has watched a lesson.

Comment: When the JS 'ended' function gets called you need to tell the server (through an API call). From there you'll probably want to store that info in the database.

Comment: @maxpleaner. How do I do that?

Comment: With Javascript. Just make an XMLHttp request to PUT some `{user_id: 1,  video_id: 2, watched: true}` data to a Rails controller action

Comment: @RandomUser2002 what specifically are you unsure about? I would recommend doing a bit of reading on what is AJAX and how to use it. The rest of this is just typical Rails MVC.

Comment: You need to start by creating a join table which joins users and lessons where you will store the "flag". If you where to to store it on the lessons table you could only keep track of a single user.